# Faster ExtJs 4 learning methodology

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs, extjs4

How can a JQuery Ninja cross over to ExtJS as fast as possible? Given that ExtJS 3.x is now obsolete, how can one quickly grip concepts in Ext JS 4. Hardly can one find a book on Ext JS 4 online. The documentation is quite forward but complex. Ext Js has many components, and each component has several APIs e.g. a Grid has very many ways of manipulating its view e.t.c. What learning flow may work for me to quickly not skip anything on components, views, controllers e.t.c. I would want to write good Ext JS code in a period of 2 months from now.
please suggest methods of learning Ext JS 4

NOTE: the writer has never used Ext Js wether in older versions of it or the new

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you may wish to refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394182/best-reference-book-for-extjs-4)

Also not that a few books are available now like [this one](http://www.imed-edition.net/extjs4easy/index.html)  and [another one](http://loianegroner.com/2011/08/my-book-extjs-4-first-look/) which is in a review phase but the most comprehensive guide will always be the documentation which you can get [here](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/). Otherwise you are not supposed to find any hardship because its all javascript.

Answer (score 4):

Two months ago I've started with Ext JS project without having previous experience with it. Can't say it was hard to learn. Ext JS is designed really cleverly. I've been learning only from official documentation and google. First I've read the official tutorials, after that was exploring reference, many helpful examples can be found there. Books about libraries and frameworks, especially about such well-documented like Ext JS are wasting of time in my opinion. If you have previous experience with JS and know about OOP it should be easy to learn Ext JS.

Comment: I totaly agree with bjornd, but I would add, that given the extjs 4 is mvc architecture I would suggest to read their forum. If you start a new application from scratch is best to know exactly how to design your application. Pages like : http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?131671-Advanced-MVC-Best-Practices and http://www.sencha.com/learn/architecting-your-app-in-ext-js-4-part-2 are really usefull

Answer (score 2):

Check the statup guide: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/guide

The best way to learn is see the examples : http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/example

Learn by videos: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/video

Once you are comfortable, read the api docs: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api